# Quantum Uncertainty in Measurement of Fundamental Quantities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Fundamental constants (such as electron rest mass or charge, which are stated with high precision and, I think, are believed to be certain), I believe are verified by measurements that involve some sort of position or momentum or energy change of the measurement apparatus. Therefore, since the apparatus has inherent internal quantum uncertainties, these constants cannot be measured with certainty above a quantum limit.

I am wondering, if something cannot be measured with certainty, even though it is theoretically certain, is it really proper to call it a constant? That is, does the quantum uncertainty in the measurement of these constants constitute an epistemological or ontological uncertainty?

I am trying to get my head around this, so please pardon any obvious confusion that I exhibit...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a "constant" is a quantity in physics that is independent of environmental factors. Quantum uncertainty, though it can change the value measured for the constant, does not constitute an environmental factor (i.e. you can't change the quantum uncertainty in the measurement and see how the value of the constant is affected). Therefore, constants are still constant.

Comment: As an aside, this supports my opinion that most philosophical questions are centrally a matter of conflicting definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Assuming electron rest mass is measured via an apparatus change in position, momentum (or other observable with inherent quantum uncertainty) then it is impossible to measure electron rest mass  more accurately than beyond the quantum uncertainty inherent in the apparatus. Then, isn't electron rest mass inherently uncertain, even though it is constant? But, in that case, there would be a conjugate variable to the electron's rest mass, which I believe there is not. So confused re: ontological vs epistemological uncertainty of electron rest mass.

Comment: Actually, my above comment would imply the existence of a wave function and associated operator for the rest mass of an electron.